# Creating circles inside of an circle in Manim?

Tags: python, manim

I want to create [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzDQ5.png) image with manim. I created [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0Lky.png) image with the following code:

```py
class Circles(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        circleOne = Circle()
        circleTwo = Circle()
        circleThree = Circle()
        
        circleOne.shift(LEFT)
        circleTwo.shift(UP)
        circleThree.shift(RIGHT)

        self.add(circleOne, circleTwo, circleThree)
        self.wait(1)
```

How is it possible to put one big circle around my manim animation that it looks like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzDQ5.png)?

Answer (score 0):

I just added another circle with a bigger radius than the other circles:

```py
%%manim -qm AlignToTest

class AlignToTest(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        circleOne = Circle(radius=3.8)
        circleTwo = Circle()
        circleThree = Circle()
        circleFour = Circle()
        
        self.add(circleOne, circleTwo, circleThree, circleFour)
        self.wait(1)
```

Here is the correct imitation of the image:

```py
%%manim -qm AlignToTest

class AlignToTest(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        circleOne = Circle(radius = 2.4)
        circleTwo = Circle(radius = 2.4)
        circleThree = Circle(radius = 2.4)
        circleFour = Circle(radius=3.8)
        
        circleOne.shift(LEFT, UP)
        circleTwo.shift(DOWN*1.4)
        circleThree.shift(RIGHT, UP)
        
        self.add(circleOne, circleTwo, circleThree, circleFour)
        self.wait(1)
```